# Autofac + Factory Method Pattern

Tags: c#, design-patterns, autofac

### BACKGROUND

According to Gang of Four the factory method pattern is used for

> Define an interface for creating an object, but let subclasses decide
>   which class to instantiate. The Factory method lets a class defer
>   instantiation it uses to subclasses.

Instead I am using it to have asynchronous construction of classes that have time consuming constructors. Lets assume this class

```
public class MyClass
{
    private readonly IA _a;

    private MyClass(IA a)
    {
        _a = a;
    }

    public static MyClass Create(IA a)
    {
        var instance = new MyClass(a);
        instance.InitializeAsync().Wait();
        return instance;
    }

    public static async Task<MyClass> CreateAsync(IA a)
    {
        var instance = new MyClass(a);
        await instance.InitializeAsync();
        return instance;
    }

    private Task InitializeAsync()
    {
        return Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Task.Delay(5000).Wait();
        });
    }
}
```

The constructor is private so you are forced to get instances through one of the Create methods. To request an instance asynchronously I would use `await MyClass.CreateAsync()` to create an instance of this class. There are indeed use cases where uninitialized instances are a bad thing, and the factory method pattern can solve this for us.

In this simplified case where `MyClass` only has one dependency `IA` I can register the component as follows:

```
_builder.Register(c => MyClass.Create(c.Resolve<IA>()))
    .As<MyClass>()
    .InstancePerDependency();

_builder.Register(c => MyClass.CreateAsync(c.Resolve<IA>()))
    .As<Task<MyClass>>()
    .InstancePerDependency();
```

I have registered both sync creation and async creation. Lets exemplify async creation by letting Autofac resolve the class for us:

```
var myInstance = await IoCProxy.RootLifetimeScope.Resolve<Task<MyClass>>();
```

I am very happy with this solution so far. I can hide the call to create inside autofac registration, so for someone resolving MyClass, the syntax will be just as normal, but with the added benefit of being able to `await`.

### PROBLEM

My only problem is that I am forced to manually resolve each of the dependencies defined in the `Create()` method. For this example I have only one dependency `IA` but for many of my classes I am injecting 10+ dependencies. For constructor injection Autofac uses reflection to walk through all of the constructor arguments, but when using `Register()` I sidestep this functionality. Is there another way to ask Autofac to automatically resolve arguments for me?

Comment: See [Constructors Should Be Simple and Stupid](http://brendan.enrick.com/post/Constructors-Should-Be-Simple-and-Stupid) and [Injection Constructors should be simple](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/03/InjectionConstructorsshouldbesimple/). I think you are looking at this problem wrong. Your constructors shouldn't be doing more than assigning dependencies. If they are taking too long it is a code smell indicating you are breaking this rule and/or the container lifetime(s) of one/some dependencies are too short. You have added a lot of complexity to try to sidestep the real problem.

Comment: That is a very valuable opinion and Mark Seemann gives very good reason why to keep the constructor simple (fast creation of object graphs and the S in SOLID). However I still do not have a good spot to do complex initialization. Mark Seemann even discards having a separate Initialize function because of temporal dependency with other properties. This is exactly the reason why I wanted to move this code to the constructor. So where do I put such code?

Comment: Mark Seeman has actually answered a lot of questions regarding IoC + initialization here on stackoverflow. They all have the same answer: Abstract Factories. So I will read up and come back with an answer incase no one beats me to it.